# Correct call from EV perspective? [PLO]

Tags: pot-odds

Hero (CO): 9d8c7d4c (stack $178)

Action folds to HJ ($206), who limp $2. Hero raises to $6 from CO. Button and SB fold. BB calls ($232). HJ mcalls. Pot: $24

Flop: 2c6sAs

BB and HJ check. Hero bets $16. BB calls. HJ folds. Pot: $56
Hero thinks BB on a draw.

Turn: 7c (Hero now has a pair, open-ended and flush draw)

Hero bets $41 ($111 left). BB raises hero all in. Hero immediately puts BB on a set.

Hero figures 33% equity (2:1 dog). Pot is now 56+41+152= ~$250. Hero needs to call $111 to win $250. Roughly 2.5 to 1 as a 2:1 underdog.

Is Hero right to call at this point? (Considering calculating pots after being reraised like this).

[image]

Comment: Question, how did you workout 33% equity ? Would be great to see your logic here, as it reads like you just thought eeh 33% why not.

Comment: Also I don't want you to read the above comment as you're wrong, but it will help understanding how you got that number is all :)

Comment: I turned an opened straight draw and my backdoor flush draw came live. Had 15outs (3 5s, 3 10s, 9 clubs) x 2.2% = ~33%

Answer (score 1):

You have 13 outs as 2 clubs pair the board. You also can't be sure clubs (non nut flush) and 4s Ts (flushes your straight) are clean. According to [simulation](http://www.propokertools.com/simulations/show?b=2c6sAs7c&g=oh&h1=9d8c7d4c&h2=22%2A%2A%2C66%2A%2A%2CAA%2A%2A%2C77%2A%2A&s=generic), your equity is closing 28%, so it's a close fold (0.28*362 = 101).

Comment: What about sevens?